# How to add seconds in a PHP date time

Tags: php, datetime

How can I add second(s) in a date time. 
ex. I have date time 2009-01-14 06:38:18 
I need to add -750 seconds in that date
and want result in datetime

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert that date to a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp), where such operations are trivial:

```
$unix_timestamp = strtotime('2009-01-14 06:38:18');
$new_string = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_timestamp - 750);
```

Answer (score 2):

strtotime() also supports some date/time arithmetic.

```
$ts = strtotime('2009-01-14 06:38:18 -750 seconds');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

or e.g.

```
$ts = strtotime('2009-01-14 06:38:18 next monday');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts);
```

prints 2009-01-19 00:00:00