# PHP datetime add one second

Tags: php, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842974/php-date-time)

Trying to add one second to a datetime that is input by the user
$values['start_date_'.$j.'-'.$i] is a valid datetime string, however the following code is throwing an error

```
$priceStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($values['start_date_'.$j.'-'.$i]));
date_modify($priceStart, '+1 second');
$priceStart =date_format($priceStart, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The error is "date_modify() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in... on line..."
same error follows for date_format()

what is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: you're absolutely correct and that solved my problem. how do I delete this question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`date()` gives you a string. `date_modify` needs a DateTime object.

The easiest way to do what you want is simply adding one to the value returned by `strtotime()`:

```
$priceStart = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($values['start_date_'.$j.'-'.$i]) + 1);
```

Or, you can create a DateTime object:

```
$priceStart = new DateTime('@' . strtotime($values['start_date_'.$j.'-'.$i]));
```

and the rest of your code should start working.

Comment: +1. Exactly what I was going to say about the DateTime class. For more info take a look at the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 25):

Use a `DateTime` object instead. It's much more powerful and easy for this one.

```
$priceStart = new DateTime("@" . strtotime($values['start_date_'.$j.'-'.$i]));
$priceStart->modify("+1 second"); //You're pretty much done here!
echo $priceStart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //Just to see the result.
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer. It uses the recommended model `DateTime` and also reads better when reviewing later.